# Why code can't update User date ? (use api_token authorization)

Tags: laravel, api

update can't modify User date
use api_token connection

return content show ok
but user date not update, Stay the same

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' ,
        'email' => 'unique:users|email',
        'password',
    ]);


    Auth::user()->update($request->all());

    return 'user updated successfully';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the rest of the data for your `user` is updating correctly through your`update()` method, make sure the `fillable` field for the user date (whatever your user date field is called) is set on your **User** model.

At the top of your **User** model, look for `$fillable`, something like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'yourDateField'  // Make sure your date field is included
];
```